# Can I screen share an OS X computer to several viewers over VNC?

Tags: macos, remote-desktop, screen-sharing

I want to give a demo to people remotely. I want them to be able to use any VNC client to view my current Mac desktop. Can I use the built-in screen sharing features to do that? I'm using Mountain Lion (10.8.2). I don't want to set up a special "guest" account. I don't want to share my account password with them. Everything I try under "Screen Sharing" gives the VNC user a Mac login screen, and doesn't connect to the existing desktop. When I enable the "remote management feature" it connects directly to the existing session with full control. I don't want all the viewers of my demo to have full control of the desktop, although that may be an acceptable work-around.

(Note: I posted this on superuser.com, and I think it should go here instead, but I don't know how to "move" it.)

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge the answer to your question is 'No'. I do the same thing and I use GoToMeeting or GoToWebinar. They are commercial products that cost money but they work really well. (I'm not affiliated in any way... I just use their products). I give demos all the time with GoToMeeting. The monthly fee was totally reasonable for what I do.